# in-app micro purchases with paypal, without using a web interface?

Tags: java, paypal, in-app-purchase

I'm writing utilities in Java and other languages I would like to charge a small a subscription fee for. The Paypal micro payments for digital goods look like a working solution for this as a contractual basis, however, their implementation as far as I can tell is always dependent on some web browser based intermediate step.

The way I would like to implement this is completely in-app similar to the following flow:

- My application checks with paypal if the subscription is current/present.
- If not, a dialog is presented to the user that asks for their paypal details.
- They can choose between several subscription models, or restore an already purchased subscription.
- My application stores a unique purchase/subscription UID locally which it uses to check with paypal whether the subscription is current.
- Once paid, the customer can manage their subscription through their Paypal web interface (i.e. nothing I need to implement at my end)
- Every time my application starts on their computers, it contacts paypal with the stored subscription UID to find out whether their subscription is still current.

Can anyone shed some light on how/whether this is possible?

Thanks!

- Balt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot currently access PayPal's Digital Goods micropayments solution except through a web browser integration. It is part of PayPal's web-based classic/pro product suite.

If you want or need an in-app solution look at PayPal's in-app product sets, either the PayPal Mobile Payment API/SDK or (better, IMO) the Braintree APIs that incorporate PayPal payments. You won't get the micropayment pricing & related features but you can get a good chunk of what you are looking for.

A bit of background:

PayPal has many products and unfortunately the products differ substantially in both integration style and payment capabilities. In other words, what you can do in one integration style you may not be able to do in another integration style. This is largely a historical artifact from 15 years of evolution on the fast-moving web (and differences in how secure various integration styles have been understood to be over time), but that doesn't help you the customer out much.

Perhaps unsurprisingly the deepest/most flexible products are the oldest ones, Website Payments Standard/Express Checkout/Pro -- but unfortunately these have the oldest integration styles. They predate smartphones (and hence apps) and even the web APIs are now pretty dated.

The newest products, the REST APIs and Braintree integrations, are undergoing the most rapid evolution. Ultimately these will have even more functionality than the older products, although probably not *identical* functionality (so it may not always be exactly a 1:1 translation to update from old to new). If these new products offer enough for you to get started, use them. If not, fall back on the old stuff and live with the integration limitations.